# Go module is found and replaced, But not required

Tags: go, go-modules

I am getting a weird error when I am trying to build my go code.

```
$ make install
go version go1.16 windows/amd64
bin/check_go_version 1.14.4
plugin/loader/preload.sh > plugin/loader/preload.go
go fmt plugin/loader/preload.go >/dev/null
go install "-asmflags=all='-trimpath=C:\Users\Deepak Dash\go\src'" "-gcflags=all='-trimpath=C:\Users\Deepak Dash\go\src'" -ldflags="-X "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs".CurrentCommit=8f9a2b7-dirty" ./cmd/ipfs
cmd\ipfs\daemon.go:32:2: module github.com/ipfs/go-saas-endpoint provides package github.com/ipfs/go-saas-endpoint and is replaced but not required; to add it:
        go get github.com/ipfs/go-saas-endpoint
make: *** [cmd/ipfs/Rules.mk:37: cmd/ipfs-install] Error 1
```

I have worked previously with go.mods. I have replaced the GitHub package with the local module. and it's detecting the local package.

Thanks,
Deepak Dash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Go 1.16 issue which is currently investigated in [`golang/go`
issue 44529](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44529)

It includes [Jay Conrod's comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44529#issuecomment-784270371):

> `go mod tidy` and `go get` may both hit the network to look up imported packages that aren't provided by any required module.
> If a module is replace locally, the go command will look there first, but I think it may still go out to the network for other prefixes of the module path.
>
> Instead, you can add a requirement on a non-existent version while replacing that version:
>
> ```
> go mod edit -require example.com/mod@v0.0.0-local -replace example.com/mod@v0.0.0-local=../local
> ```
>
> Adding a replacement, even one without a version on the left side, doesn't automatically add that module to the build list.
> If it did, the `go` command would read its `go.mod` file and apply its requirements. That could influence selected versions of other modules, even if the replaced module didn't provide any packages.

[Bryan C. Mills from Google adds](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44529#issuecomment-784295528):

> `go mod tidy` should never do a network lookup if it could add a replaced module instead. (see [`import.go#queryImp()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/7eb31d999cf2769deb0e7bdcafc30e18f52ceb48/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/import.go#L334-L351))
>
> `go get`, on the other hand, will perform a network lookup in order to identify the true latest version, taking your replacements into account ([`query.go#Versions()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/7eb31d999cf2769deb0e7bdcafc30e18f52ceb48/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/query.go#L987-L1000)), and then that version will be replaced instead of downloaded.
> It does that so that the latest version added by go get is always consistent with `go list -m [⋯]@latest`, and so that (if possible) your require directive always specifies a valid version for downstream consumers (if any), so that they won't break when they require your module. (Downstream consumers will not pick up your replace directives, so they need a valid version.)
>
> If you are not using a proxy for the repo in question, that lookup may involve cloning the upstream repo. So that can be a pretty expensive operation. (Note that the official distributions of the go command use `proxy.golang.org` by default, but the Fedora fork of the `go` command does not.)
>
> If that network lookup fails, then `go get` will also fall back to replacement version ([`query.go#Latest()`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/7eb31d999cf2769deb0e7bdcafc30e18f52ceb48/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/query.go#L1045-L1062))

Comment: Thanks!!! 
Makes sense, yesterday I updated the go to 1.16 version and it started breaking.

Comment: To summarize: this is a side-effect of the change to default to `-mod=readonly` as of Go 1.16. Your build succeeded before because the default behavior was `-mod=mod`, which causes `go build` to implicitly add new requirements as needed. With the new default, you need to add those requirements _explicitly_ (such as with `go mod tidy` or `go get`) before building.

Comment: @bcmills Good summary. I will monitor (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44529, where you left your comment) to see if there will be any resolution or evolution to make that transition (ie " the change to default to `-mod=readonly` as of Go 1.16") smoother for the users.

Comment: `go get mycompany.com/path/to/module` fixed it for me. 

Others explained the why of it better, but the key is `go get` understands that go.mod might have a replace path that's relative and will keep stuff local when it is in fact local.

Comment: `go mod tidy` did it for me.